# R Defined Function to review numeric column and calculate log

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a dataframe with 10 vars. Three are factors and seven are numeric. I want to write a defined function that looks through each column and determines if it is numeric; and if it is numeric calculate the log.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple way with `dplyr` package -

```
your_df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, log)
```

As per comment, if you want to keep the original variables and add the logs as new variables -

```
your_df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(LG = ~log))
```

Example -

```
head(iris) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, list(LG = ~log))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length_LG Sepal.Width_LG Petal.Length_LG Petal.Width_LG
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa        1.629241       1.252763       0.3364722     -1.6094379
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa        1.589235       1.098612       0.3364722     -1.6094379
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa        1.547563       1.163151       0.2623643     -1.6094379
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa        1.526056       1.131402       0.4054651     -1.6094379
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa        1.609438       1.280934       0.3364722     -1.6094379
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa        1.686399       1.360977       0.5306283     -0.9162907
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. What if I want to keep the main variable and the log variable. For example: keep "Sepal.Length" and the logged one as "Sepal.Length_LG"

Answer (score 0):

Using "dplyr" package you can select only numeric columns and calculate log. In my example I used "iris" dataset:

```
iris_1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris %>% select_if(is.numeric), log)) 

> head(iris_1)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     1.629241    1.252763    0.3364722  -1.6094379
2     1.589235    1.098612    0.3364722  -1.6094379
3     1.547563    1.163151    0.2623643  -1.6094379
4     1.526056    1.131402    0.4054651  -1.6094379
5     1.609438    1.280934    0.3364722  -1.6094379
6     1.686399    1.360977    0.5306283  -0.9162907
```